# Problems with document.addEventListener vs element.addEventListener

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I was working on some code I wrote and I had this problem where an eventListener I added to a dynamically created element, but it does not "fire" aka work.

```
var eleButton = document.createElement("button");
eleButton.innerText="Post";
eleButton.type="submit";
...
eleButtonContainer.appendChild(eleButton);
```

And the eventlistener was a basic "click"

```
eleButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("Hello World");
});
```

That did not work, so i searched around and could not find any answers. I finally found a work around of using document and checking whether or not that element was check or not. So my resulting code became this:

```
var eleButton = document.createElement("button");
eleButton.innerText="Post";
eleButton.type="submit";
eleButton.id = "usrResponseSubmit";

console.log(eleButton);
document.body.addEventListener('click',function(){
   if(event.target.id == "usrResponseSubmit"){
       console.log("ok now it works");
   }
});
```

This works fine, but it still makes me question about the code atop. I willing to take the "if it werks it works" route, but I would also still like to use the eleButton.addEventListener route because that was what I always used.

So my two questions are:

1. is using document.addEventListener bad?
2. why does eleButton.addEventListner not work?

Before you say, but it works on my end, my code is kinda crap and long.  Essentially, I have this eleButton nested in a container that is nested in a container ... (x~10-20). I don't think this is necessarily the problem. But I also have some other eventListeners that "may" overlay with eleButton. I'm not too sure that's the case as i've been trying and testing everything I can.

I have also pulled the eleButton and appended it to an existing object and the event did fire. Can someone give me a run down of when events do not fire?

Comment: Can you please create a [mre] that reproduces this issue? It could be that you've removed the element and replaced it with another one? Difficult to say what the exact issue could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your code, maybe you just misspelled something. here i made a codepen example you can check.

```
html:
<div id="btnCon"></div>
```

...

```
JS:
const eleButtonContainer = document.querySelector('#btnCon')

var eleButton = document.createElement("button");
eleButton.innerText="Post";
eleButton.type="submit";

eleButtonContainer.appendChild(eleButton);

eleButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("Hello World");
});
```

[the example on codepen](https://codepen.io/navab/pen/abqxyyK)

Comment: Yes. Nothing is wrong. From what I am guessing is that the backend part of my website is broken. And the lag in the ajax caused nothing to appear. It was not JS at all.